# How do i preselect a guid value in a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-mvc

I am trying to sort out an issue with my dropdowns so i am trying to use a property to fix it on the page however when i read the value in on selectedindexchanged.

```
public Guid _appointmentType { get; set; }

protected void Page_Init(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        Guid _guid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);

        _shifts = _dal.GetShiftPatternById(_guid);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
        var dlManagersSource = _dal.GetManagers();
        rdManagers.DataSource = dlManagersSource;
        rdManagers.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
        rdManagers.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
        rdManagers.DataBind();

        var ddlShiftPatterns = _dal.GetShiftPatternTypes();
        rdAppointmentType.DataSource = ddlShiftPatterns;
        rdAppointmentType.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
        rdAppointmentType.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
        rdAppointmentType.DataBind();



        }

      rdDayOfWeek.SelectedValue = _shifts.dayOfWeek.ToString();
      rdManagers.SelectedValue = _shifts.manager_Id.ToString();
      txtDescription.Text = _shifts.Description;
      rdStartShift.SelectedDate = _shifts.startdate;
      rdShiftEnd.SelectedDate = _shifts.endDate;
}

protected void rdAppointmentType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{
        _appointmentType = new Guid(rdAppointmentType.SelectedValue);
}
```

But when i come to reload the record it has saved it as null instead of the value of obv I have a save event that saves the entity back but my question is i do not think the method i am using to match the guid to watch is already in dropdown is working as its staying at the first ite Please Select.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_bio">Appointment Type<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-7">
        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="rdAppointmentType"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdAppointmentType_SelectedIndexChanged"    DefaultMessage="Please Select"  runat="server" Skin="Bootstrap"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I think my main problem is down to this line

```
 rdManagers.SelectedValue = _shifts.manager_Id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're losing contents of property `_appointmentType` on `PostBack`. You can preserve it in `ViewState`

instead of:

```
public Guid _appointmentType { get; set; }
```

use property like this

```
private Guid _appointmentType
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["_appointmentType"] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (Guid)ViewState["_appointmentType"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["_appointmentType"] = value;
    }
}
```